# SSRS - Direct changes to report database does not reflect report

Tags: database, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, rdl

I'm actually developing reports with SSRS (2008R2). Due to some reasons I'm required/decided to change the .rdl (XML) file directly in order to create a dynamic set of columns in a tablix.

My modifications are working fine and the BIDS shows all my direct changes to the .rdl file in design view, but of course not in the `live` report.

I found in the reporting database in the table `Catalog` the field `Content` which holds a copy of the source-rdl. If I modify the content stored in this field (e.g. change a column title) the report in the report viewer still shows the old column title and not the new one. I tried to delete the browser cache, but this didn't work.

So either the report viewer caches the report and/or I need to change any other field in  the database to let the report server or viewer know that there is a change, but cannot figure out which one.

I hope someone can point me to the right direction or ideally to the solution.

Yes, I'm aware that doing changes to the reporting database is not a recommended way :-)

Thank you very much!

Comment: What happens if you restart SSRS? Do the changes pop up then?

Comment: Good idea, but didn't solve the problem

Comment: After a little while I figured out, that the way I was planning to solve my problem was not good. Instead there is a much more easy way I have totally overseen: change the source rdl and deploy it via rs.exe - works perfectly fine.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. You should post that as an answer and accept it, so others can easily spot it.